# Homogeneous eigenvalue sampling of a sparse unitary matrix

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix, numerical-methods

I work with Julia, but I think the question is more general. Suppose that one wants to find the spectrum of a very large (sparse) unitary matrix `U` numerically. As is reported in many entries, diagonalizing by brute force using `eigs` ends without eigenvalue convergence.

The trick would be then to work with simpler expressions, i.e. with

```
U_Re = real(U + U')*0.5                                                                             
U_Im = real((U - U')*-0.5im)
```

My question is, is there a way to obtain a uniform sampling in finding the eigenvalues? That is, I would like to obtain, say `10e3` eigenvalues for `U_Re` and `U_Im` in the interval `[-1,1]`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure how *uniform sampling of the eigenvalues* would work, but I think you are looking for [ARPACK](https://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/). ARPACK would use matrix-vector products to find your eigenvalues, so I am not entirely sure if the Real/Im decomposition is required in this case (hard to say without knowing a lot about the `U`).

Also, you might want to look at [FEAST](http://www.ecs.umass.edu/~polizzi/feast/) algorithm, which would benefit a lot from the [given search contour](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4031).

I am not aware of the existing linking of Julia to those libraries, but I don't think it is a problem since Julia can call C functions.

Here, I gave some brief ideas, and [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to find the right crowd. However, a lot more details about `U`, its sparsity, size, and what does "uniform sampling of eigenvalues in the interval" means would be required.

Comment: [Arpack.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/Arpack.jl) wraps ARPACK.